# Numpy ndarray multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 3D numpy ndarray

```
A=np.array([[[1, 1],
             [1, 1],
             [1, 1]],

            [[2, 2],
             [2, 2],
             [2, 2]]])

B=np.array([[[ 2,  0],
             [ 0,  2]],

            [[ 2, -2],
             [-2,  2]]])
```

I want to create the AB array with elements AB<sub>ijk</sub>=∑<sub>m</sub> (A<sub>ijm</sub>*B<sub>imk</sub>) where the summation is only over the m-index (repeated) and not over i (that is in turn repeated).

In other words I can obtain di AB ndarray with this for loop

```
for i in range(2):
    AB[i,:,:]=np.dot(A[i,:,:],B[i,:,:])
```

and AB is equal to

```
array([[[ 2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

Is there way to avoid the for loop? How can I obtain the AB array with tensordot or einsum?

Thank you for your answers, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a sufficiently recent NumPy (1.10+), you can do

```
AB = np.matmul(A, B)
```

or (if you also have Python 3.5+):

```
AB = A @ B
```

If you don't have NumPy 1.10+, you can do

```
AB = np.einsum('ijm,imk->ijk', A, B)
```

For large J/M/K dimensions, especially if you have a good BLAS, it might also be worth considering the explicit `for` loop with `dot`. The BLAS matrix multiply might save more time than the overhead of more interpreted Python loses. I think `np.matmul` and `@` are supposed to take advantage of the same things `dot` does, but I don't think `np.einsum` does.

Comment: Confirmed: `einsum` does not use BLAS as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

`ABijk=∑m (Aijm*Bimk)` translates to

```
AB = np.einsum('ijm,imk->ijk', A, B)
```

I think the `matmul` operator will also handle this

```
AB = A @ B
```

since it takes the normal `dot` on the the last 2 dimensions, carrying the rest along as free baggage.

Test those and let me know if they work.